# Opening a file (.RDS) in SSRS project freezes Visual Studio

Tags: xml, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have a Visual Studio solution with reporting project. In the reporting project, when I open an .RDS file and then navigate to the 'Parameters' window, Visual Studio freezes every time. In the same project, some of the other RDS files work fine.

I found some notes on line to look in APPDATA for an ActivityLog (`%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\`). I have some "APP DATA/Visual Studio" folders, but there is no file named ActivityLog.

When I use a text editor (NPP) to compare the Working/Broken file, I get a warning about "different encodings". Any idea what the different encodings message means? The XML schemas looks pretty much the same to me on the files (Working/Broken).

[Sherlock-Public/Account_Scoring.rsd](https://github.com/sherlockspreadsheets/Sherlock-Public/blob/main/Troulbeshoot/Account_Scoring.rsd)

[Sherlock-Public/DoubleCheck.rsd](https://github.com/sherlockspreadsheets/Sherlock-Public/blob/main/Troulbeshoot/DoubleCheck.rsd)

[image: VS freezes RDS file]

Version (Visual Studio Community 2019)

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.11.22
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.11.22+33130.400
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Community
...
SQL Server Data Tools   16.0.62205.05200
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

SQL Server Integration Services   16.0.948.0
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 16.0.948.0

SQL Server Reporting Services   15.0.19528.0
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers 
Version 15.0.19528.0
...
```

Comment: I tried to open the files but they are blank, looking via your github repo it shows all the lines deleted (unless I'm missing something obvious)?